# Interval of convergence of a series

Tags: power-series

How to get the interval of convergence for the given function,

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2+x-x^2}$$

I have computed the Maclaurin series and the generalized power series as follows however I am unable to proceed with the valid interval of convergence. Kindly help.
$$\frac{1}{2+x-x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\alpha }\frac{1}{6}x^n(2(-1)^n+2^{-n}) \\ 
\frac{1}{2+x-x^2}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}x+\frac{3}{4}\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+ \ldots$$

Comment: for $n\gg 1$ the coefficient is dominated by $2(-1)^n$ since $2^{-n}\to 0$ so the radius is the same as $\sum x^n$ which is $1$.

Comment: What could be the interval? would that be (1, 0.5)?

Comment: There are chances it is $(-1,2)$ the points that annulates denominator but it would be better to recenter in $x_0=0.5$ and calculate the new radius of convergence.

Comment: Great, thanks. This helps. I had confusion around 0.5. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways to find the radius of convergence $r$. Let $f(x) = \sum c_n(x-a)^n$.

$$r = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}} \right| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}}$$

For you, $c_n = (2(-1)^n + 2^{-n})/6$. I would suggest using the first test as a result. As $n$ grows without bound, the $2^{-n(+1)}$ terms will go to zero, and the absolute value will get rid of the $(-1)^{n(+1)}$ terms, letting you reach a conclusion easily.

As for the interval itself, for the general $f$ described above, it is $(a-r,a+r)$. For you, $a=0$.

Comment: So the interval is (-1,1)? If so, the graph of the function not really limits the case especially at 0.5

Comment: The interval is indeed $(-1,1)$. That said, I don't know what you refer to by "the case [...] at $0.5$."

Comment: Thank you. This helped.

Answer (score 3):

We can also  calculate  the   partial  fraction decomposition 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2+x-x^2}=\frac{1}{3(x+1)}-\frac{1}{3(x-2)}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
and obtain this  way geometric series. We  see the radius  of convergence of  the geometric series  at $x=0$  is $1$ resp. $2$. So,  the  radius of convergence  of the left-hand  side of (1) is the minimum distance from $x=0$ to the  nearest singularity at  $x=-1$  and the interval of convergence is   $(-1,1)$.